# Adding CSS to jQuery dynamically added element inside of Polymer Component

Tags: jquery, css, polymer

I'm having problems adding a CSS class to a jQuery created element inside of a Polymer component.

Here is the Polymer component:

```
<dom-module id="image-add">

<style>

    .image {
        height: 100%; 
    }

</style>

<template>
    <div id = "container">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "image-add",
        properties: {
            images_to_add: {
                type: Array
            }
        },
        ready:function(){

            var shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this;
            var container = $(shadowRoot).find('#container');

            var new_image = $("<div></div>")
            new_image.css({"background-image":"url('" + this.images_to_slide[1] + "')"})
            new_image.addClass("image");
            new_image.appendTo(container);

        }
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

As you can see im passing in an array of images into the Polymer component which im using to place in the background of a dynamically added div with the help of jQuery. Now jQuery then adds the class of "image" to the dynamically added div but the problem I face is I don't see the effects of adding that class. i.e. the div doesn't go to a height of 100%. and when i inspect the div it has the class but no effects of the class.

Why isn't the effects of the class being applied to this dynamically added div? I'm guessing it has something to do with Polymer as normally this would work.

PLEASE NOTE: I have to be able to generate these divs at any point in time dynamically. And the background image style is being applied fine already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can do it much more simply with pure polymer using the [`<template is="dom-repeat">`](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat) tag. This is more declarative and uses the native `<img>` tag which is more in keeping with the polymer philosophy. It's also far fewer lines of code. Here's a working example with some adorable kittens.

```
<dom-module id="image-add">

  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{imageUrls}}" as="imageUrl">
      <img id="{{calcImageId(index)}}" src="{{imageUrl}}">
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "image-add",
      properties: {
        imageUrls: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [
              'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300',
              'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      calcImageId: function(index) {
        return 'image_' + index;
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

[image: kitten]
[image: kitten]

Now, adding another kitten dynamically is a snap.

```
document.querySelector('image-add').push('imageUrls', 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300')
```

And there we have it, our third kitten.

[image: kitten]
[image: kitten]
[image: kitten]

Comment: Thats all well and good but I HAVE to be able to generate them dynamically at any point in time, so sadly this solution wont work for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JulianPoole You can add content dynamically just by pushing or popping off of the imagesToAdd array using polymer's push and pop helpers. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah I hear what you are saying.. but i cant add individual things like "id"s to each one before they go live :/ which is kinda a problem... I need to add and remove them dynamically with individual content and attributes.

Comment: Also where does <img src="{{item}}"> come from in your code?

Comment: @JulianPoole `item` comes from the `<dom-repeat>` and represents a member of the `items` array. If you want to alias it to `image`, you can do so with the `as` tag. You can easily add individual things like "id"s to each one before they go live using declarative syntax with data binding. If you really want to do it imperatively with jQuery, you can, but you're fighting the library. That's why your solution is so many more lines of code.

Comment: @JulianPoole I added custom IDs the declarative way to the answer in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

you might use the following

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "image-add",
        properties: {
            images_to_add: {
                type: Array
            }
        },
        ready:function(){

            var shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this;
            var container = $(shadowRoot).find('#container');

            var new_image = $("<div>")
            new_image.attr("style","background-image:url('" + this.images_to_slide[1] + "')"); // in this way you are adding inline style to the generated div
            new_image.addClass("image");
            new_image.appendTo(container);

        }
    });
</script>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: How is this different from what I've got as far as applying the the "image" class? This just changes how the background image style is added which is working fine already, this isn't the issues. The issue is that im not seeing any effects of the "image" class being applied to the div. Not that the background image styling isn't working.

Comment: add in the css image { height: 100% !important;}

Comment: haha no thats not going to fix it :p The styles aren't being over written or anything.. otherwise that would be a easy fix, the class style simply isn't even showing up in the list of applied style in the first place when i inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to make the element using:

```
document.createElement('div');
```

and assign it to a variable:

```
var some_veriable = document.createElement('div');
```

and then you can stuff around with it with jQuery adding classes and styles etc:

```
var some_veriable = document.createElement('div');
$(some_veriable).attr("id","image_1").addClass("image animating").css({"background-image":"url('" + this.images_to_slide[current_image_number] + "')"});
```

before adding it to the Polymer DOM where the classes you have set up will now work.

```
var some_veriable = document.createElement('div');
$(toLocal).attr("id","image_1").addClass("image animating").css({"background-image":"url('" + this.images_to_slide[current_image_number] + "')"});
Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(some_veriable)
```